# Parse a .txt file

Tags: python, parsing, text-files

I have a .txt file like:

```
Symbols from __ctype_tab.o:

Name                  Value   Class        Type         Size     Line  Section

__ctype             |00000000|   D  |       OBJECT   |00000004|     |.data
__ctype_tab         |00000000|   r  |       OBJECT   |00000101|     |.rodata


Symbols from _ashldi3.o:

Name                  Value   Class        Type         Size     Line  Section

__ashldi3           |00000000|   T  |       FUNC      |00000050|     |.text
```

How can i parsr this file and get the functions with type FUNC ?
Also,from this txt how can i parse and extract .o name ?

How can i get them by column wise parsing or else how.

I need an immediate help...Waiting for an appropriate solution as usual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might cost less than the use of regexes though i am not totally clear on what you are trying to accomplish

```
symbolList=[]
for line in open('datafile.txt','r'):
if '.o' in line:
    tempname=line.split()[-1][0:-2]
            pass

if 'FUNC' not in line:
    pass

else:
    symbolList.append((tempname,line.split('|')[0]))
```

I have learned from other posts it is cheaper and better to wrap up all of the data when you are reading through a file the first time.  Thus if you wanted to wrap up the whole datafile in one pass then you could do the following instead

```
fullDict={}
for line in open('datafile.txt','r'):
    if '.o' in line:
        tempname=line.split()[-1][0:-2]
    if '|' not in line:
        pass
    else:
        tempDict={}
            dataList=[dataItem.strip() for dataItem in line.strip().split('|')]
            name=dataList[0].strip()
            tempDict['Value']=dataList[1]
            tempDict['Class']=dataList[2]
            tempDict['Type']=dataList[3]
            tempDict['Size']=dataList[4]
            tempDict['Line']=dataList[5]
            tempDict['Section']=dataList[6]
            tempDict['o.name']=tempname
            fullDict[name]=tempDict
            tempDict={}
```

Then if you want the Func type you would use the following:

```
funcDict={}
for record in fullDict:
    if fullDict[record]['Type']=='FUNC':
        funcDict[record]=fullDict[record]
```

Sorry for being so obsessive but I am trying to get a better handle on creating list comprehensions and I decided that this was worthy of a shot

Comment: Well, you're my competitor, but I've got to +1 since I didn't know the 'substr' not in 'larger string' idiom.  Thanks!

Comment: but since dictionary is mutable its ceating a great problem.Since the field 'Name' will be repeating in other .o's they r getting overwritten. Any solution for this ?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear.  I lot of times I create tuples as dictionary keys.  Without fully knowing your data I would set the key to

fullDict[(name, tempname)]=tempdict

Answer (score 9):

```
for line in open('thefile.txt'):
  fields = line.split('|')
  if len(fields) < 4: continue
  if fields[3].trim() != 'FUNC': continue
  dowhateveryouwishwith(line, fields)
```

Comment: Seriously? In a markup-language environment like SO, where markdown or HTML is the norm, you're critiquing the exact number of indent spaces?

Comment: It would be nice if this solution could be adapted to solve the other part of the OP's question: how to track the .o file. I like this answer's brevity compared to my own but it doesn't solve the total problem.

Comment: Do you have any idea who ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_Martelli ) you are saying eww to, Joe?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic approach.  What do you think?

```
# Suppose you have filename "thefile.txt"
import re

obj = ''
for line in file('thefile.txt'):
    # Checking for the .o file
    match = re.search('Symbols from (.*):', line)
    if match:
        obj = match.groups()[0]

    # Checking for the symbols.
    if re.search('|', line):
        columns = [x.strip() for x in a.split('|')]
        if columns[3] == 'FUNC':
            print 'File %s has a FUNC named %s' % (obj, columns[0])
```

Comment: You're going to get an IndexError (index out of range) with that, if given that text verbatim.

Comment: Whoops, good point.  I think the newer version won't have that since it only splits if there is a | character in the line.